# Is xor the fastest operation the ALU can do?

Tags: assembly, cpu, xor, boolean-logic

Is `xor` the fastest operation the ALU can do on a byte? My prof was saying it is because there's nothing simpler than checking to see if two things are the same or not. Is this the right way to think of `xor` that `1` is returned if the operands are different and `0` if they are the same?

Comment: At the processor level there's gonna be no difference between all the bit-to-bit operations, `&`, `|`, `^`, `~`. But in terms of gate latency, NANDs and NORs will probably be the fastest.

Comment: Gate latency would not be of concern in a synchronous circuit. Keyword: critical path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This all depends on how your CPU works. In practice, ALU operations on modern chips are all one clock cycle -- but even that statement is over-generalized, because there's often more than one way to do arithmetic.

SIMD features allow you to process more than one piece of data per clock cycle, which increases throughput. Certain instructions on certain architectures (like x86's [`LEA`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer#Load_Effective_Address)) allow you to compose multiple arithmetic operations into a single instruction which is again executed in a single clock cycle, making that faster in certain perspectives.

On most architectures, ALUs don't just return a value, they also modify flags: overflow (carry), zero, etc. The time required to perform an arithmetic operation can change if other instructions depend on these flags, especially if there are conditionals involved. Check the manual.

Also, "fast" in terms of latency is different than "fast" in terms of operations per second. An XOR might take one clock cycle to execute in the ALU, but take another clock cycle until the result becomes available for use in another instruction, flags or otherwise. And even then, out-of-order execution can make it *seem* like the result is available immediately, but that's because the chip is shuffling around your instructions to keep itself busy.

Answer (score 5):

Actually NAND and NOR are the simplest binary operations due to their CMOS implementation (roughly speaking they have a low number of gates). NOT is the simplest operation of course because all it does is invert the bits. In terms of an actual CPU however, even the add/subtract operations are likely to only take a single cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that argumentation; the ALU has several operations implemented.  Firstly, it clearly depends on the actual CPU, secondly it depends on the overall CPU architecture (Load-store, etc).

One plausible argument, however, I quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation):

> On some computer architectures, it is more efficient to store a zero in a register by xor-ing the register with itself (bits xor-ed with themselves are always zero) instead of loading and storing the value zero.

This is, because no additional operands are required.

Comment: I wonder which architectures they refer to (i.e. modern ones)?

Comment: x86 favors `xor eax, eax` not because it's faster than `mov eax, 0`, but because the machine code ends up smaller (2 bytes instead of 5). Smaller instructions means better use of the available cache and memory bandwidth.

Comment: Back in the bad old days of CGA, XOR AX,AX (or was it AH?) vs. MOV AX,0 was the difference between getting snow and the display and not getting snow on the display when trying to stuff characters on the screen during the horizontal retrace interval!  The extra byte of the MOV instruction delayed it just enough to conflict with the video chips memory read!

Comment: In the first place, that isn't what `xor` does!